# PHP Array from MySQL is not empty but has an empty entry - how to avoid

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to check whether an entry exists (one or more) in our database. However, even when I know there are no entries, I am getting an array which has a first entry of zero. Therefore it is not empty and I am not getting what I need.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = $yfbid_number AND timestamp BETWEEN (NOW()- Interval 1 DAY) AND NOW()");
    $array[] = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $array[] = $row['column'];
    }
    ?>
```

When doing print_r on an array which should be empty, I am getting: ( [0] => Array ( ) ) and therefore count is 1 and not zero, which messes up my code. Any ideas how to get to a truly empty array in this situation? 
I'd rather not delete this entry but avoid it in the first place, because in most use cases I will get either an empty array or one that only has one entry (a real entry), in which case I will want to easily distinguish between the two. (as it is now, both give a count of 1 entry, which is very bad for our porpuses). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
$array[] = array();
```

to

```
$array = array();
```

With your version, if $array doesn't already exist, PHP will first create an array, then append an empty array to it. So you end up with a 1 element array whose only member is an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

`$array[] = array();`  should be `$array = array()`.  Right now, you are appending an array element to an array that is initialized.  Turn notices on and you'll get a complaint about an undefined variable (probably).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` to determine how many entries you'll get.  Then you KNOW that the result will be a useful answer, and can make or not make a subsequent query on the basis of your result.